# How do can I check a logical comparison is TRUE or FALSE in WHERE Statement in TSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, comparison, where-clause

How can I accomplish this query so that I can check the logical comparison's result is FALSE:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ...
INNER JOIN table3 ...
INNER JOIN table4 ...
WHERE ( ( table1.Value IS NULL) AND 
         ( table2.Value IS NULL) AND
         ( table3.Value IS NULL) AND
          ( table4.Value IS NULL) ) -- Here I want to ADD something like IS FALE; 
                                    --How can I do this?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the NOT operand

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ...
INNER JOIN table3 ...
INNER JOIN table4 ...
WHERE NOT ( ( table1.Value IS NULL) AND 
            ( table2.Value IS NULL) AND
            ( table3.Value IS NULL) AND
            ( table4.Value IS NULL)
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options

**NOT**

`...(Table4.value IS NOT NULL)...`
`...NOT (Table4.value IS NULL)...`

**CASE**

`CASE WHEN (<complex comparison> = somevalue THEN 1 ELSE 0) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ...
INNER JOIN table3 ...
INNER JOIN table4 ...
WHERE (
        NOT(    
         ( table1.Value IS NULL) AND 
         ( table2.Value IS NULL) AND
         ( table3.Value IS NULL) AND
         ( table4.Value IS NULL)
          ) 
      )
```